# How do I create a FieldDeclaration given an IField (Eclipe plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Given that I have access to an IField field (parsed from another Java file), how do I create a FieldDeclaration in order to add it to a AST?

```
    String varName = field.getElementName();
    String typeName = Signature.toString(field.getTypeSignature());

    VariableDeclarationFragment fieldFrag = ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment();
    fieldFrag.setName(ast.newSimpleName(varName));
    FieldDeclaration field = ast.newFieldDeclaration(fieldFrag);
    Type fieldType = ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName(typeName));
    field.setType(fieldType);
    field.modifiers().add(ast.newModifier(modifierKeyword));
```

The above

Type fieldType = ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName(typeName));

only works only if typeName is not a java keyword.  Is there another way to simply create a fieldDeclaration with all the IField info (modifier, type, variable)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way using copySubtree:

```
    AST ast = targetCompilationUnit.getAST();

    FieldDeclaration oldFieldDeclaration = ASTNodeSearchUtil.getFieldDeclarationNode(field, sourceCompilationUnit);
    Type oldType = oldFieldDeclaration.getType();

    Type newType = (Type) ASTNode.copySubtree(ast, oldType);
```

Then newType can be used to plug it into a FieldDeclaration

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment();
fragment.setName(ast.newSimpleName("log"));
final FieldDeclaration declaration = ast.newFieldDeclaration(fragment);
declaration.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName("Logger")));
declaration.modifiers().addAll(ASTNodeFactory.newModifiers(ast, Modifier.PRIVATE | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL));
```

and if you want to init it:

```
MethodInvocation methodInvocation = ast.newMethodInvocation();
methodInvocation.setName(ast.newSimpleName("getLogger"));
methodInvocation.setExpression(ast.newSimpleName("Logger"));
TypeLiteral typeLiteral = ast.newTypeLiteral();
typeLiteral.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName(className)));
methodInvocation.arguments().add(typeLiteral);
fragment.setInitializer(methodInvocation);
```

Comment: i don't think this will work when the SimpleType is a primitive